# MYSQL Select update query multiple joins error

Tags: php, mysql, select, join

i am trying to update a variable row, in a variable table. This is my query:

// EDIT: removed double...

```
UPDATE `ec`.`category_id` AS `category_id`,`e`.`title` AS `title`,
    `r`.`first_name` AS `first_name`,
    `r`.`last_name` AS `last_name`,`r`.`email` AS `email`,
    `r`.`comment` AS `comment`,`r`.`amount` AS `amount`,
    `r`.`published` AS `published`,`r`.`transaction_id` AS `transaction_id`,
    `r`.`register_date` AS `register_date`,
max((case `f`.`id` when 1 then `v`.`field_value` else '' end)) AS `pand`,
max((case `f`.`id` when 52 then `v`.`field_value` else '' end)) AS `achternaam`,
max((case `f`.`id` when 53 then `v`.`field_value` else '' end)) AS `voornaam`,
max((case `f`.`id` when 20 then `v`.`field_value` else '' end)) AS `gebdat`,
max((case `f`.`id` when 32 then `v`.`field_value` else '' end)) AS `geslacht`,
max((case `f`.`id` when 31 then `v`.`field_value` else '' end)) AS `kleinkind`,
max((case `f`.`id` when 21 then `v`.`field_value` else '' end)) AS `straat`,
max((case `f`.`id` when 54 then `v`.`field_value` else '' end)) AS `postcode`,
max((case `f`.`id` when 55 then `v`.`field_value` else '' end)) AS `plaats`,
max((case `f`.`id` when 26 then `v`.`field_value` else '' end)) AS `telthuis`,
max((case `f`.`id` when 27 then `v`.`field_value` else '' end)) AS `telmir`,
max((case `f`.`id` when 28 then `v`.`field_value` else '' end)) AS `gsmdeelnemer`,
max((case `f`.`id` when 29 then `v`.`field_value` else '' end)) AS `gsmpapa`,
max((case `f`.`id` when 56 then `v`.`field_value` else '' end)) AS `gsmmama`,
max((case `f`.`id` when 30 then `v`.`field_value` else '' end)) AS `graad`,
max((case `f`.`id` when 88 then `v`.`field_value` else '' end)) AS `bestelling`,
max((case `f`.`id` when 34 then `v`.`field_value` else '' end)) AS `eigendom`,
max((case `f`.`id` when 57 then `v`.`field_value` else '' end)) AS `zodiac`,
max((case `f`.`id` when 42 then `v`.`field_value` else '' end)) AS `tshirt`,
max((case `f`.`id` when 39 then `v`.`field_value` else '' end)) AS `helpdag`,
max((case `f`.`id` when 40 then `v`.`field_value` else '' end)) AS `helpinfo`,
max((case `f`.`id` when 36 then `v`.`field_value` else '' end)) AS `vervoerjanee`,
max((case `f`.`id` when 37 then `v`.`field_value` else '' end)) AS `vervoerinfo`
from ((((`dat_eb_field_values` `v` join `dat_eb_registrants` `r` on((`v`.`registrant_id` = `r`.`id`)))
join `dat_eb_fields` `f` on((`v`.`field_id` = `f`.`id`)))
join `dat_eb_events` `e` on((`r`.`event_id` = `e`.`id`)))
join `dat_eb_event_categories` `ec` on((`ec`.`event_id` = `e`.`id`)))
where ((`ec`.`category_id` = 4) and (`e`.`published` = 1))
SET $rowname=$newvalue WHERE transaction_id=$transid
```

Normally this query uses SELECT as the first argument instead of UPDATE.
The last line was also added by me.
$rowname, $newvalue and $transid are all defined and it geives me the following error:

```
Not unique table/alias: 'first_name'.
```

Thanks in advance, Laurent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for UPDATE clause is something like this

```
UPDATE table JOIN table1 ON table.field = table1.field SET table.field2 = 'value' WHERE table.field3 = 'value2'
```

You don't provide any fields to select as UPDATE clause does not select anything. So, you should remove the fields from SELECT clause and add the WHERE pats after SET.

```
UPDATE 
((((`dat_eb_field_values` `v` join `dat_eb_registrants` `r` on((`v`.`registrant_id` = `r`.`id`)))
join `dat_eb_fields` `f` on((`v`.`field_id` = `f`.`id`)))
join `dat_eb_events` `e` on((`r`.`event_id` = `e`.`id`)))
join `dat_eb_event_categories` `ec` on((`ec`.`event_id` = `e`.`id`)))

SET $rowname=$newvalue

WHERE ((`ec`.`category_id` = 4) and (`e`.`published` = 1)) AND transaction_id=$transid
```

Comment: Normally this query uses SELECT as the first argument instead of UPDATE. Read all post.

Comment: Normally, it uses SELECT. And he wants to make UPDATE from this SELECT clause.

Comment: when i execute this, it tells me: unknow column (content of $newvalue) in 'field list'... any idea?

Comment: You should look at the generated SQL statement first to look for any SQL errors. As I don't know your $rowname, $newvalue and $transid values, I cannot tell anything. Even if they're even inserted in your SQL statement. You should also avoid SQL Injection. In your case, I think putting $newvalue in single quotes would solve it.

Comment: im sorry, $newvalue is a user entered string (eg. test123test) $rowname is the row to update it in, also chosen by the user (eg. first_name) and $transid is a unique 8 digit code used as identifier. (eg. PLGGTSWG).

Comment: Also keep in mind that you must escape your user-inputted values to avoid SQL injection. `$newvalue = mysql_real_escape_string($newvalue)`. Also do the same for $transid and validate the $rowname

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here

```
`r`.`first_name`,`r`.`first_name` AS `first_name`,
```

You have ambiguous aliases.

Comment: This is just a minor thing, looking at the whole thing he is trying to accomplish. `first_name` in this case should not be an alias, but just a field. By removing this `first_name`, other issues would arise, for example, that there is no table `first_name`.

Comment: Why do you think that aliases for tables only?

Comment: I meant that in this case, it is understood as the table alias, not the field alias. `Not unique table/alias: 'first_name'.` Just by removing the duplicate alias, other problems would arise.

Comment: ok, i have removed the double, but it gives me: 'max((case `f`.`id` when 1 then `v`.`field_value` else '' end)) AS `pand`, max((c' at line 2

Comment: As I said :) The syntax of the UPDATE clause is just wrong in this case.